# How can I make *.form files show in the NetBeans GUI?

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm unable to view the *.form files in the GUI structure of a NetBeans project. But these files are present in the directory and are visible through Windows Explorer.

What can I do to see them in the Files or Projects windows?

Answer (score 2):

The files are not displayed in the NB file explorer views 'by design'.  They are metadata for the Swing UI editor and so they are not designed to be hand edited.  They are updated when you work on the layout of your swing components in the NetBeans Swing UI editor.

Comment: I understand the significance of the .form files and I do not wish to modify them. But untill now there were visible but after some changes to the design. I do not see them being displayed. So I feel my question still remains unanswered.

Answer (score 2):

You can view and modify a `.form` file by opening the associated `.java` file and clicking the *Design* button atop the source view of the file.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to view it in netbeans IDE.
However, you can see it in the location where the project is saved.

documents > Netbeans_Projects > project_name > build > classes > project_name

it's visible in the above mentioned path.