# Why my form in Java Swing in NetBeans got separated from panel and there is ' ? ' on its logo? What does it mean?

Tags: java, forms, swing

I had closed my NetBeans project and after some time I reopened my NetBeans and opened my project but there's a new file generated named same as my previous one but with extension of `.form` and question mark on its logo. Which file is that? Why it happens? How can I correct it?

The picture is mentioned below.

[image: This is the image of my netbeens and the file is marked]

I just want to correct this mistake.

Comment: [Turns out these shouldn't show up normally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10876128/how-can-i-make-form-files-show-in-the-netbeans-gui). See also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/61312084/5133585

Comment: yes it should be but if i delete it the design view of this file will be gone